# awk mixed trailing and leading underscore

Tags: awk

To keep lines which have numbers below  100(hundred) on their third field, how can I deal with trailing and leading underscores using  awk script.

Here is sample input:

```
asd 5.0 _84_ 34
sds 3.8 _340_ 56
sds 3.8  99  56
sds 3.8 _340_ 56          
ddd 288 _26_ 45
sdf 321 _374_ 53 
tyu 321 _39_ 89 
sds 3.8 120  56 
wer 3.8 _28_ 345
sds 3.8  45  56
tre 230 _265_ 90  
rtu 389 _372_ 45
bnm 965 _270_ 745
fgh 856 _44_ 346
sds 3.8 107  56
```

expected output will be:

```
 asd 5.0 _84_ 34
 sds 3.8  99  56            
 ddd 288 _26_ 45
 tyu 321 _39_ 89 
 wer 3.8 _28_ 345
 sds 3.8  45  56       
 fgh 856 _44_ 346
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$3 ~ /^_?[[:digit:]]{1,2}_?$/'
```

That will match an optional underscore, one or two digits followed by an optional underscore.

Answer (score 0):

try this awk one-liner:

```
kent$  awk -F'_| +' 'NF==4&&$3<100||NF>=6&&$4<100' file
asd 5.0 _84_ 34
sds 3.8  99  56
ddd 288 _26_ 45
tyu 321 _39_ 89
wer 3.8 _28_ 345
sds 3.8  45  56
fgh 856 _44_ 346
```

Comment: It works fine, but when tried to print numbers above hundred it leaves line with number 120 in it, and with large files,like trace file from ns2, it also prints numbers not in the range

Comment: @user2677682 pls paste the line with `120`

Answer (score 0):

Using gawk:

```
 awk 'match($3, /([0-9]+)/, a) {if (a[1]<100) print $0}' input
```

Comment: @user2677682 - that error message means you are using old, broken awk (/usr/bin/awk on Solaris). Use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk or even better install gawk.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{line=$0; gsub(/_/,"")} $3 < 100{print line}' file
asd 5.0 _84_ 34
sds 3.8  99  56
ddd 288 _26_ 45
tyu 321 _39_ 89 
wer 3.8 _28_ 345
sds 3.8  45  56
fgh 856 _44_ 346
```